# Can $xu_x=yu_y$ with $u(x,0)=\sin(x)$ be solved by the method of characteristics?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

So I'm trying to solve the above equation by the method of characteristics, but I'm getting stuck after parametrizing and then putting stuff back into terms of $x$ and $y$.

What I get is

$$\frac{dx(r,s)}{ds} = x \implies x(r,s) = c_1 e^s$$
$$\frac{dy(r,s)}{ds} = -y \implies y = c_2 e^{-s}$$
$$\frac{dz(r,s)}{ds} = 0 \implies z = c_ 3$$

and using the conditions, I end up with

$$x(r,s) = re^s$$
$$y(r,s) = 0$$
$$z(r,s) = \sin(r)$$

When I try to get an answer in terms of $x$ and $y$, I can't seem to figure out how to do it, since I'm not really sure how to get an equation for $s$? Am I doing something wrong? Can someone help explain what it is? I've been stuck on this for an hour and I really don't think I'm getting anywhere...

Comment: Hans gave you the answer but in order to solve the problem, note that the characteristics come from $$\frac{dx}{x} = -\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{du}{0}$$ Solving the first equality gives $xy = C_{1}$ (equivalent to eliminating $e^{s}$ from your solutions for $x$ and $y$) and the last ratio implies $u = C_{2} = f(C_{1}) = f(xy)$. Applying the initial condition, you require $$u(x,0) = f(x \cdot 0) = f(0) = \sin(x)$$ impossible.

Comment: Ohhh yes, I see. This makes sense as well, thank you! I was doing a practice set that said to solve the questions by the method of characteristics IF possible, and looking at this, I was kind of confused if it even was possible, though I still wanted to try, but thank you, this comment helps as well! 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x$-axis is a characteristic curve, so you're bound to run into trouble when the initial values are given there. Indeed, at the point $(x,0)$ you have $x u_x = x \cos x$ and $y u_y = 0$, so you can't satisfy the PDE at those points.

Comment: Ahhh I see. So this PDE isn't solvable anyway?

Comment: Not with the given condition for $u(x,0)$, no.

Comment: Alright, alright, thank you!